# How do I deal with irregularly spaced time series?

Tags: r

I havea CSV file containing various sensor readings.

It looks as though it represents four different time series, temperature, motion, power, and battery, with each reading taken at a slightly different time.

```
dat <- read.csv(text = "id,device_id,type,value,timestamp
1432,4,temperature,21,2015-06-01T00:00:00Z
1433,4,motion,0,2015-06-01T00:00:15Z
1434,4,power,0,2015-06-01T00:00:30Z
1435,4,battery,4.16,2015-06-01T00:00:46Z
1448,4,temperature,21,2015-06-01T00:17:00Z
1449,4,motion,0,2015-06-01T00:17:15Z
1450,4,power,0,2015-06-01T00:17:30Z
1451,4,battery,4.16,2015-06-01T00:17:45Z
1464,4,temperature,21,2015-06-01T00:33:57Z")

str(dat)

'data.frame':   9 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ id       : int  1432 1433 1434 1435 1448 1449 1450 1451 1464
 $ device_id: int  4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
 $ type     : Factor w/ 4 levels "battery","motion",..: 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4
 $ value    : num  21 0 0 4.16 21 0 0 4.16 21
 $ timestamp: Factor w/ 9 levels "2015-06-01T00:00:00Z",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

How can I manipulate the data to plot the four graphs against the time?

Comment: R import csv, R plot, R parse datetime, ...

Comment: [The R tag info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info) has some good starting points.

Comment: `data <- read.csv("<name_of_file.csv>");` Or, using `fread` from the `data.table` package: `data <- fread("<name_of_file.csv>");` Type autodetection will get most of it though you'll probably have to convert the timestamp field to something R understands.

Comment: Well, after considerable googling it seems that R just doesn't deal with this sort of data well at all, and the file needs a fair bit of preprocessing so that there's a common time variable against which every reading is recorded, pretending that they happened at the same time. If I've missed something obvious, please let me know.

Comment: @JohnLawrenceAspden That is utter rubbish. I'd be surprised if this took more than a couple of lines of R to read, get the timestatmp in the right format, and plot all series with ggplot.

Comment: timestamp's easy enough: ds.t$timestamp<-strptime(ds.t$timestamp,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ") , and I can select out a subsequence like this:
ds.t <- subset (ds, type == "temperature"), but the underlying problem of having all the data on slightly different time axes seems very difficult to deal with.

Comment: @JohnLawrenceAspden Again, no, it's not a problem to have data on slightly different time points. If those too-eager to close this hadn't, I'd have shown you how to do this now. It's just a little too long to post coherently into a comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily do this in R using just a few lines of code.

The first step is to convert the timestamp into a POSIXct date. The easiest way of doing this is to force this column as class `character` during import:

```
dat <- read.csv(colClasses = c(timestamp = "character"),
                text = "id,device_id,type,value,timestamp
                1432,4,temperature,21,2015-06-01T00:00:00Z
                1433,4,motion,0,2015-06-01T00:00:15Z
                1434,4,power,0,2015-06-01T00:00:30Z
                1435,4,battery,4.16,2015-06-01T00:00:46Z
                1448,4,temperature,21,2015-06-01T00:17:00Z
                1449,4,motion,0,2015-06-01T00:17:15Z
                1450,4,power,0,2015-06-01T00:17:30Z
                1451,4,battery,4.16,2015-06-01T00:17:45Z
                1464,4,temperature,21,2015-06-01T00:33:57Z")
```

Then convert to `POSIXct`.  See `?strptime` for the meaning of `%F` (full date) and `%T` (full time):

```
dat$timestamp <- as.POSIXct(dat$timestamp, format = "%FT%TZ")
str(dat)

'data.frame':   9 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ id       : int  1432 1433 1434 1435 1448 1449 1450 1451 1464
 $ device_id: int  4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
 $ type     : Factor w/ 4 levels "battery","motion",..: 4 2 3 1 4 2 3 1 4
 $ value    : num  21 0 0 4.16 21 0 0 4.16 21
 $ timestamp: POSIXct, format: "2015-06-01 00:00:00" "2015-06-01 00:00:15" ...
```

Then plot using `ggplot2`. For example:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(x=timestamp, y = value, group = device_id)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(type ~ ., scales = "free_y")
```

[image]

Comment: Pretty much what I intended to show, though I'd have simulated more data so the plot look *fancy* :P

Comment: @Spacedman You can fix that, as shown in the edit, by flipping the formula to `type ~ .` and specifying separate y-axis scales via `scales = "free_y"`

Comment: I didn't realise the data were flat on any scale... :)

Comment: i believe there's a new feature in ggplot2 to place the panel strips on the left side, where they would in effect replace the axis title with something more meaningful